# Open URL on Menu Item Click

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swift3

I need to Open a URL when the user clicks on a Menu Item.
Currently I'm using the following code

```
url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/test")
NSWorkspace.shared().open(url)
```

This works fine from a Button.But I cannot connect a Segue from the Menu Item to the view controller inorder to  setup an IOAction,so that I can write the necessary code.

How can I solve this problem? Please advice.

Comment: You could not connect IOAction with file ?

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk I tried dragging and dropping the Menu Item segue to view controller.swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Implement the method as `IBAction` in the view controller.
- Connect the `NSMenuItem` to **`First Responder`** (red cube) of the Application Scene and select the method.

If there are multiple implementations of the method the framework executes the first in the responder chain.

Comment: I Implemented the IBAction.. Clicked on the ViewController to show the red cube.Pressed control and tried dragging and connecting... but I cannot connect it to the menu item.

Comment: Control-drag from the NSMenuItem to the red cube (in the same scope)

Comment: The red cube does not appear until I click on the ViewController.And there is no connection happening after control+dragging..

Comment: If you are using storyboard click on the Application Scene (**not** the View Controller Scene). There is the red cube I'm talking about. If you are using XIB, the red cube is next to the File's Owner object

Comment: Im using Storyboard(Xcode 8). I can see the Red Cube in the Main View Controller ,on the control + dragging ,the segue line appears .. but I cannot connect it to the MenuItem.

Comment: Once again **not** the (Main) View Controller, the **Application Scene** (where AppDelegate and MainMenu belongs to)

Comment: Just one more question... Please ... Is there a way to remove the search box that appears under Help Menu?

Comment: If you don't want to provide help, remove the entire Help Menu

Comment: Tried that .. Created a New Menu named `Help` .. the Search Bar Appears there.

Comment: Strange. I'm using a few projects with a very restricted menu item set (without Help Menu). Please ask a new question. Maybe there is somebody who knows the solution.

Comment: I already have asked a question.No answers..It seems that if the Menu Name is Help,the search Bar Appears there by default.

Comment: Sorry.. but another question..I want to show a custom `About` window...so I created a new view controller and dragged the `About` Menu Item to the View controller.Set the Segue to Modal.When the View Controller shows,There is this `Maximise` button enabled...I have disabled it in the window controller.How can I disable this button? Please advice.

Comment: Never mind :) Got it..`self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(NSWindowStyleMask.resizable)`

Answer (score 5):

Segues are for opening new views or windows from your app. You should implement your function as ordinary `@IBAction` in your view controller or app delegate, and connect `action` under `Sent Actions` in the Connections Inspector with the First Responder in the storyboard scene. You will find your action method there. Cocoa touch will automatically enable or disable the menu item weather the view controller is in the responder chain. If you implement the action method in the app delegate the menu item should always be enabled, because the delegate is always in the responder chain.

```
@IBAction func openURL(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/test")
    NSWorkspace.shared().open(url)
}
```